# How to extract day-of-the-week from datetime format from XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, datetime-format, dayofweek

I am trying to extract the day in my XSLT stylesheet from the datetime format of XML file. I am using XSLT 1.0 and XPATH not Python, that's my limitation. 
Here is the one example of my code on XML document:

```
 <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2010-08-09T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2010-08-10T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2010-08-08T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2010-08-09T14:00:00Z">
            <element type="forecast_icon_code">12</element>
            <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">8</element>
            <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">15</element>
            <text type="precis">Chance of light rain.</text>
        </forecast-period>
```

I want to extract the forecast of Monday from the list. I tried to search on google and found day-of-the-week function works for this but couldn't implement properly. I am new to this XSLT and XML. So, I am not getting idea how print the day from the give time.

Can you give me some idea?

Comment: You don't explain why the `day-of-the-week` function couldn't be implemented. You'll need some kind of calculation to obtain the day of the week based on the timestamps you have in the document.

Comment: None of the dates above is a Monday. You'll have to give us more information if you want a better answer.

Comment: Ya, I have copied only some lines of code only. The whole xml file is too big to paste here. I just want to get idea how to parse timestamp from xml and find the day. I have to make the list of weather information for each days.

Comment: So you're not using python at all? Was the python tag just a typo?

Comment: @MuMind Ya, that was a mistake. But I had already removed that tag.

Comment: @PedroRomano Ya, I have already mentioned in my question that I am new to XML and XSLT. However, i tried to implement that function, got no output.

Comment: Are you using XSLT **1.0** or **2.0**?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of information here, but I usually turn to the lxml package for such things.  If you know the path to the data that you want, it should be very simple. I suggest you review the following [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) and edit your question as needed with more specific questions to accomplish your task.  I hope this helps.  If you post additional info I will try to refine my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two questions: how to parse out the timestamp from XML, and how to find the day of week from the timestamp. For the first, you should use an XML parser, such as [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or python's built-in [xml.parsers.expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html).

Once you have the timestamp string, it's easy to convert to a weekday name using the [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library:

```
import dateutil.parser
start_time_local = "2010-08-07T00:00:00+10:00"
weekday_name = dateutil.parser.parse(start_time_local).strftime('%A')
```

Comment: Good point...  I almost get the feeling he wants to go the other direction.  Like, I know what day that I need the data for (this Monday), but how to I get it out of the xml file. I could be wrong here.  The question is still a bit confusing to me.  Maybe he will post more information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am only using XSLT to extract the data, that's my limitation. So, couldn't do experiment with your code in python.